# Large number of entries: how to calculate quickly the total?

Tags: database, accounting

I am writing a rather large application that allows people to send text messages and emails. I will charge 7c per SMS and 2c per email sent. I will allow people to "recharge" their account. So, the end result is likely to be a database table with a few small entries like +100 and many, many entries like -0.02 and -0.07.

I need to check a person's balance immediately when they are trying to send an email or a message.

The obvious answer is to have cached "total" somewhere, and update it whenever something is added or taken out. However, as always in programming, there is more to it: what about monthly statements, where the balance needs to be carried forward from the previous month? My "intuitive" solution is to have two levels of cache: one for the current month, and one entry for each month (or billing period) with three entries:

- The total added
- The total taken out
- The balance to that point

Are there better, established ways to deal with this problem?

Comment: Well, my application does a lot more than that, sending texts is just a "detail". Plus, each user will only send a few -- but _all_ of the users together will send a large amount. No, I am not writing a bulk email and bulk sms sending system, honestly :D I's actually a kick-butt booking system/CRM!

Comment: But yes, I am definitely late. I got "sidetracked" by the part of the project where you write the underlying libraries... But I am actually developing things now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Largely depends on the RDBMS.

If it were SQL Server, one solution is to create an [Indexed view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (or views)  to automatically incrementally calculate and hold the aggregated values.

Another solution is to use triggers to aggregate whenever a row is inserted at the finest granularity of detail.